# how do I copy a lot of images onto a canvas in PHP?

Tags: php, image, gd

I have witten a function that copies some images onto a canvas and saves it to a file. My code is at the bottom of the post.

The code works fine when i try to copy 15 image onto the canvas, but when i try to copy 30 it just stops. No errors or exceptions...

I hope one of you can help me out :)

```
    $img        = imagecreatefromjpeg( $image );
    $imgWidth   = imagesx($img);
    $imgHeight  = imagesy($img);

    // CREATE CANVAS AND FILL WITH WHITE
    $canvas     = imagecreatetruecolor( $guidelines['canvasW'] * $dpi, $guidelines['canvasH'] * $dpi );
    $color      = imagecolorallocate( $canvas, 255, 255, 255 );
    imagefill( $canvas, 0, 0, $color );

    // COPY THE IMAGES ONTO THE CANVAS
    foreach( $guidelines['imageGuide'] as $guide ):

        $bestFit    = bestFit( $imgWidth, $imgHeight, $guide['W'] * $dpi, $guide['H'] * $dpi );
        if( $bestFit['rotate'] ) {
            $output = imagerotate($img, 90, 0);
        } else {
            $output = imagerotate($img, 0, 0);
        }
        imagecopyresampled($canvas, $output, $guide['X'] * $dpi, $guide['Y'] * $dpi, 0, 0, $bestFit['x'], $bestFit['y'], imagesx($output), imagesy($output));

        imagedestroy($output);
    endforeach;
```

$guidelines is an array. Here is an example which will copy 16 images onto the canvas

```
    $guidelines = array(    'canvasW' => 20,
            'canvasH' => 30,
            'imageGuide' => array(
                        array('W' => 18,    'H' => 13,  'X' => 1,   'Y' => 1.5),

                        array('W' => 3.5,   'H' => 4.5, 'X' => 1.25,    'Y' => 15),
                        array('W' => 3.5,   'H' => 4.5, 'X' => 4.75,    'Y' => 15),
                        array('W' => 3.5,   'H' => 4.5, 'X' => 8.25,    'Y' => 15),
                        array('W' => 3.5,   'H' => 4.5, 'X' => 11.75,   'Y' => 15),
                        array('W' => 3.5,   'H' => 4.5, 'X' => 15.25,   'Y' => 15),

                        array('W' => 3.5,   'H' => 4.5, 'X' => 1.25,    'Y' => 19.5),
                        array('W' => 3.5,   'H' => 4.5, 'X' => 4.75,    'Y' => 19.5),
                        array('W' => 3.5,   'H' => 4.5, 'X' => 8.25,    'Y' => 19.5),
                        array('W' => 3.5,   'H' => 4.5, 'X' => 11.75,   'Y' => 19.5),
                        array('W' => 3.5,   'H' => 4.5, 'X' => 15.25,   'Y' => 19.5),

                        array('W' => 3.5,   'H' => 4.5, 'X' => 1.25,    'Y' => 24),
                        array('W' => 3.5,   'H' => 4.5, 'X' => 4.75,    'Y' => 24),
                        array('W' => 3.5,   'H' => 4.5, 'X' => 8.25,    'Y' => 24),
                        array('W' => 3.5,   'H' => 4.5, 'X' => 11.75,   'Y' => 24),
                        array('W' => 3.5,   'H' => 4.5, 'X' => 15.25,   'Y' => 24),
                    ),
                );
```

Comment: Do you have error-reporting on? It usually runs out of memory in this kind of cases...

Comment: have you checked your error logs and also try put `error_reporting(0)` within your application, there should be a trace somewhere

Comment: Is $dpi defined anywhere? You use it in the sample, but don't set it.

Comment: Normally PHP errors is just written on the page when they occour. So it's strange that they don't do now. I don't know how to find my error log. I am on a shared host :( $dpi is set to 100 elsewhere in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to guess that you are using too much RAM with this job. `ImageCopyResampled` has to write a lot to RAM with this job you have, and images can take up a lot of memory. Check [memory_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) in your php.ini file, try increasing it and see if you can get through more/all of your images being written to the canvas. Good luck!

Comment: I dont understand why it takes up so much ram. I call imagedestroy($output); at the end of the forloop, so it clears the memory and leaves only $img and $canvas in the memory right? I have tried to increase memory limit, and is running tests now. I hope it works :)

Comment: True, you are running `imagedestroy()` and I'm sure that helps, but its possible that the canvas itself is too much. Its also possible (don't quote me, just theorizing) that everytime you write a new image to the canvas, the old version of the canvas stays in RAM, so after 15 iterations you have 15 copies of the canvas in ram (getting larger and larger with each iteration).

Comment: I have thought about that too, but I couldn't find an answer :( But I got i working now. I increased the memory limit, and I think thats what triggered it. Now i just got a problem with the execution time. I have tried to use set_time_limit( 300 ); in my foreach loop, but it still times out after 200 seconds (which is set in php.ini). I am not in safemode, why doesn't it work, do you know?

Comment: Hmm, I can research that but you could start by trying `ini_set('max_execution_time',300);`. Let me know if that works. By the way, make sure you are placing all of this before the `foreach` loop, can't tell if thats what you were saying in your comment.

Comment: When I read the docs I got the impression that the code extends the time limit by the number of seconds stated in the brackets. Therefore I put it inside the foreachloop so it gives the script 300 extra seconds to run. Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: Ah, I see what you are trying to do. Have you tried it outside the `foreach` to see if placing it in there is causing the issue?